# Read line by line from a variable in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script variable which is multi-line.
How do i traverse this variable to read it line by line and process each line the way I want?

Comment: There is a similar question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-can-i-read-line-by-line-from-a-variable-in-bash/605491#605491; I have written an answer there.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Consider the following multi-line variable

```
x=$(echo -e "a\nb\nc d e")
```

and a simple process for each line: just `echo` it with a prefix=`LINE:` and with single quotes around the line. Either of the following codes will satisfy that requirement:

```
while read line; do echo "LINE: '${line}'"; done <<< "$x"
```

or

```
while read line; do echo "LINE: '${line}'"; done < <(echo "$x")
```

Neither creates a subshell (so you can, e.g., set variables in the loop and access them outside of it), and both output

```
LINE: 'a'
LINE: 'b'
LINE: 'c d e'
```

But suppose instead you have

```
x=$(echo -e "a \n b\nc d e")
# note--------^--^
```

and that leading and trailing whitespace matter for your application (e.g., parsing Git porcelain). Both the above codes will give exactly the same output for the latter variable/data as for the former, which is not what you want. To preserve leading and trailing whitespace, replace `while read line` with `while IFS= read -r line` . I.e., either of the following codes

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "LINE: '${line}'"; done <<< "$x"
```

or

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "LINE: '${line}'"; done < <(echo "$x")
```

will produce

```
LINE: 'a '
LINE: ' b'
LINE: 'c d e'
```

See [Greg Wooledge's excellent Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for details.

Comment: this is a perfect solution, just curious, why not just x="a\nb\nc d e"?

Comment: @SenthilKumar, that string contains 10 charactes: 'a', '\', 'n', 'b', etc. The "\n" are not special inside double quotes. In bash, one could write `$"a\nb\nc d e"` to have real newlines embedded in the string. The "-e" flag tells `echo` to process "\n" as a new line, not two indvidual characters.

Comment: @chepner: thx, `$` was new to me, but it works with single quotes `$'a\nb\nc d e'`

Comment: @Karoly: my mistake, I used the wrong quotes. Double quotes are for `gettext` translations; single quotes are for backslash expansions.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this solution only works because `echo` adds a trailing newline; in other words, it alters the variable to parse. This might or might not be acceptable for the OP. Without the trailing newline, `read` would completely miss the last line. For details, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9789

Answer (score 5):

Although I typically use "while read" for processing multi-line variables, I recently had an instance where it removed the leading space from each line in a file. Using this instead fixed my issue:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var" | while IFS= read -r line
do
   echo "$line"
done
```

Code taken from [this Unix Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9789).

**Edit**: updated to fix last line issue as suggested by Nicolae Iotu

Comment: Nice solution, but you will need to end printf with a new line to make it process the last line: `printf '%s\n' "$var" ... `

Comment: Good point, thank you. I have updated my answer with the changes you suggested.